# Config value in html template Magento 2

Tags: magento2, configuration

```
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="configProviders" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="magepow_one_step_checkout_composite_config" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Model\CompositeConfigProvider</item>

            <item name="checkout_Extrafee_block" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Model\ExtrafeeConfigProvider</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

**And**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\ConfigProviderInterface;

class ExtrafeeConfigProvider implements ConfigProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Vendor\Module\Helper\Data
     */
    protected $dataHelper;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
     */
    protected $checkoutSession;

    /**
     * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
     */
    protected $logger;

    /**
     * @param \Vendor\Module\Helper\Data $dataHelper
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Vendor\Module\Helper\Data $dataHelper,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger

    )
    {
        $this->dataHelper = $dataHelper;
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getConfig()
    {
        $ExtrafeeConfig = [];
        $enabled = $this->dataHelper->isModuleEnabled();
        $minimumOrderAmount = $this->dataHelper->getMinimumOrderAmount();
        $ExtrafeeConfig['fee_label'] = $this->dataHelper->getFeeLabel();
        $quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();
        $subtotal = $quote->getSubtotal();
        $ExtrafeeConfig['custom_fee_amount'] = $this->dataHelper->getExtrafee();
        $ExtrafeeConfig['show_hide_Extrafee_block'] = ($enabled && ($minimumOrderAmount <= $subtotal) && $quote->getFee()) ? true : false;
        $ExtrafeeConfig['show_hide_Extrafee_shipblock'] = ($enabled && ($minimumOrderAmount <= $subtotal)) ? true : false;
        return $ExtrafeeConfig;
    }
}
```

knockout template

```
  define(
    [
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/abstract-total',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
        'Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/totals'
    ],
    function (Component, quote, priceUtils, totals) {
        "use strict";
        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                isFullTaxSummaryDisplayed: window.checkoutConfig.isFullTaxSummaryDisplayed || false,
                template: 'Vendor_Module/checkout/summary/fee'
            },
            totals: quote.getTotals(),
            isTaxDisplayedInGrandTotal: window.checkoutConfig.includeTaxInGrandTotal || false,
            isDisplayed: function() {
                return this.isFullMode();
            },
            getValue: function() {
                var price = 0;
                if (this.totals()) {
                    price = totals.getSegment('fee').value;
                }
                return this.getFormattedPrice(price);
            }
        });
    }
);

    <!-- ko -->

  <tr class="totals fee excl">
        <th class="mark" scope="row">
            <span class="label" data-bind="text: title"></span>
            <span class="value" data-bind="text: getValue()"></span>
        </th>
        <td class="amount">

            <span class="price"
                  data-bind="text: getValue(), attr: {'data-th': title}"></span>


        </td>
    </tr>   

<!-- /ko -->
```

I tried config value in Html template, please check my code here, thank you.

Comment: Have you add any plugin of LayoutProcessor?